# Bind 2 separate columns to down drop list

Tags: c#

I am using a list box for the selection of file names pulled from SQL. The drop down works fine but is there a way I can bind a description also? The thought is to have the file name and description in the drop down list side by side. The file description is also a column in the same table.

```js
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        layouts.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        layouts.DataTextField = "TextColumn";
                        layouts.DataValueField = "id";
                        layouts.DataBind();
                        con.Close();
```

Comment: Are you using dataset for it? Can you please put a little more code that how you are populating ds ?

Comment: @gaurav The data is being pulled from SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a example to bind bind two columns of data to a dropdown. Try it

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from test1", con))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    adpt.Fill(dt);
                    Dictionary<int,> lst = new Dictionary<int,>();
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        //Add values to Dictionary
                        string val = row[1].ToString() + " , " + row[2].ToString() + " , " + row[3].ToString();
                        lst.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row[0]), val);
                    }
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = lst;
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Value";
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Key";
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                }
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional property (for example, `NameDescription`) to your model and use it:

```
public class File
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // this is your file name property
    public string Description { get; set; } // this is your description property
    public string NameDescription => string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Description); // the new property which contains name and description
}
```